# ng-click() on button added with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs 1.5 to build a chat application and in the chat I want to get confirmation from the user when a certain event occurs.

I am doing this part in the success promise of the $http.get directive. After receiving the data I check data.confidence. If data.confidence is less than 0.7 I want the user to give me feedback that whether the answer was helpful of not. So in the chat log I append the feedback part dynamically once the event is triggered using jquery and once the button is clicked the ng-click is not working. However on the other button in the view the ng-click does work. Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```
app.controller('telecom_controller', function($http, $scope) {
    console.log("Telecom Controller");
    $scope.telecom_messages = [];


    $scope.message = function(){
        console.log("M3");
    };


    $scope.ask = function(){
        $scope.query = $("#telecom_query_text").val();
        $('#telecom_query_text').val('');
        $scope.telecom_messages.push($scope.query);
        console.log($scope.telecom_messages);
        $scope.loading = true;
        console.log($scope.loading);
        $scope.qs = 'http://deeplearn.zippybots.com/api/getanswer?question=' + $scope.query + '&faqset=Telecom.xlsx&format=json';

        // Scrolling Part Trial
        $("#cl_telecom").animate({scrollTop: 90000}, 3000);

       $http.get($scope.qs).
       success(function(data, status){
            console.log($scope.qs);
            console.log("Successful");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.answer);
            confidence = parseFloat(data.confidence);
            if (confidence < 0.7){
                alert(confidence);
                var r= $('<p>Did the above answer help you?<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="message()">Yes</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">No</button>');
                chat_log = document.getElementById('cl_telecom');
                $(chat_log).append(r);
            }
            else{
                // alert("Nothing to show");
            }
            $scope.telecom_messages.push(data.answer);
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.log($scope.loading);
            // Scroll Part
            $("#cl_telecom").animate({scrollTop: 90000}, 3000);
        }).
        error(function(data, success){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(data);
            $scope.telecom_messages.push("Sorry! Didn't get you....");
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.log($scope.loading);
            // Scroll Part
            $("#cl_telecom").animate({scrollTop: 90000}, 3000);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you got any errors in console?

Comment: Seems weird you would use jQuery to add it and not angular...

Comment: No i didn't get any errors on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

```
var r = $compile('<p>Did the above answer help you?<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="message()">Yes</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">No</button>')($scope);
angular.element(document.getElementById('cl_telecom')).append(r);
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope','$compile',
      function($scope, $compile) {
        var html = $compile('<a ng-click="click()" href="#">Click me</a>')($scope);
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#x')).append(html);
        $scope.click = function() {
          console.log('Yahoooooooooooo')
        }
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div id="x">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```